# Using 'UseMvc' to configure MVC is not supported while using Endpoint Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I had an Asp.Net core 2.2 project.

Recently, I changed the version from .net core 2.2 to .net core 3.0 Preview 8. After this change I see this warning message:

> using 'UseMvc' to configure MVC is not supported while using Endpoint
>   Routing. To continue using 'UseMvc', please set
>   'MvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false' inside 'ConfigureServices'.

I understand that by setting `EnableEndpointRouting` to false I can solve the issue, but I need to know what is the proper way to solve it and why Endpoint Routing does not need `UseMvc()` function.

Comment: about proper way: this doc 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#update-routing-startup-code 
states "migrate the app to Endpoint Routing if possible"

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> but I need to know what is the proper way to solve it

In general, you should use `EnableEndpointRouting` instead of `UseMvc`, and you could refer [Update routing startup code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#update-routing-startup-code) for detail steps to enable `EnableEndpointRouting`.

> why Endpoint Routing does not need UseMvc() function.

For `UseMvc`, it uses `the IRouter-based logic` and `EnableEndpointRouting` uses `endpoint-based logic`. They are following different logic which could be found below:

```
if (options.Value.EnableEndpointRouting)
{
    var mvcEndpointDataSource = app.ApplicationServices
        .GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource>>()
        .OfType<MvcEndpointDataSource>()
        .First();
    var parameterPolicyFactory = app.ApplicationServices
        .GetRequiredService<ParameterPolicyFactory>();

    var endpointRouteBuilder = new EndpointRouteBuilder(app);

    configureRoutes(endpointRouteBuilder);

    foreach (var router in endpointRouteBuilder.Routes)
    {
        // Only accept Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Route when converting to endpoint
        // Sub-types could have additional customization that we can't knowingly convert
        if (router is Route route && router.GetType() == typeof(Route))
        {
            var endpointInfo = new MvcEndpointInfo(
                route.Name,
                route.RouteTemplate,
                route.Defaults,
                route.Constraints.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => (object)kvp.Value),
                route.DataTokens,
                parameterPolicyFactory);

            mvcEndpointDataSource.ConventionalEndpointInfos.Add(endpointInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot use '{router.GetType().FullName}' with Endpoint Routing.");
        }
    }

    if (!app.Properties.TryGetValue(EndpointRoutingRegisteredKey, out _))
    {
        // Matching middleware has not been registered yet
        // For back-compat register middleware so an endpoint is matched and then immediately used
        app.UseEndpointRouting();
    }

    return app.UseEndpoint();
}
else
{
    var routes = new RouteBuilder(app)
    {
        DefaultHandler = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<MvcRouteHandler>(),
    };

    configureRoutes(routes);

    routes.Routes.Insert(0, AttributeRouting.CreateAttributeMegaRoute(app.ApplicationServices));

    return app.UseRouter(routes.Build());
}
```

For `EnableEndpointRouting`, it uses [EndpointMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c7cb8467bfce721e2d66ef3862cd8c7c1fdbb421/src/Http/Routing/src/EndpointMiddleware.cs) to route the request to the endpoints.

Answer (score 278):

I found the solution, in the following official documentation "[Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)":

There are 3 approaches:

> 1. Replace UseMvc or UseSignalR with UseEndpoints.

In my case, the result looked like that

```
  public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Old Way
        services.AddMvc();
        // New Ways
        //services.AddRazorPages();
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        });

    }
}
```

> OR
>   2. Use AddControllers() and UseEndpoints()

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

    }
}
```

> OR
>   3. Disable endpoint Routing. As the exception message suggests and as mentioned in the following section of documentation: [use mvcwithout endpoint routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-mvc-without-endpoint-routing)

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
//OR
services.AddControllers(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

Comment: This works in asp.net core 3.0 and I can use this add web API easily

Comment: It's recommended (on that page) to use `services.AddRazorPages();` instead of `services.AddMvc();`

Comment: This is a good solution if you're going through the [first mvc tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app) and upgrade from core2.1 to core3.0. This solved my issue immediately, thanks!

Comment: So they basically just slightly changed the syntax from UseMvc() to UseEndpoints().

Comment: I needed to adapt some ASP.NET Core 2.2 example code => ASP.NET 5.  OLD: `app.UseMvc(routes =>  {...});`  NEW: `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {...});`.  In other words: Option 1 worked like a charm!  Thank you!  Too bad this isn't the "accepted" reply.

Answer (score 92):

This worked for me (add in `Startup.cs` > ConfigureServices method):

```
services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
```

Comment: Simple answer, but Great answer!

Comment: I would argue about the usefulness of this answer. This answers how not why...

Answer (score 20):

The issue I found to be due to updates on the .NET Core framework. The latest .NET Core 3.0 released version requires explicit opt-in for using MVC.

This issue is most visible when one tries to migrate from older .NET Core(2.2 or preview 3.0 version) to .NET Core 3.0

If migrating from 2.2 to 3.0, please use the below code to fix the issue.

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

If using .NET Core 3.0 template,

```
services.AddControllers(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

ConfigServices method after fix as below,

[image]

Thank You

Answer (score 13):

Endpoint Routing is disabled by default on ASP.NET 5.0

Just configure as in Startup

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
    }
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 11):

You can use :
in ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

And for Configure method:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: This worked well for me, I needed to add `app.UseRouting();` though.

Answer (score 7):

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Old Way
        services.AddMvc();
        // New Ways
        //services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        });
    }
}
```

This works also in .Net Core 5

Comment: What is the difference with [NHARI Med](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61466585/52277) answer ?

Answer (score 6):

-> In ConfigureServices method - Startup.cs

```
        //*****REGISTER Routing Service*****
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddControllers(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

-> In Configure Method - Startup.cs

```
       //*****USE Routing***** 
        app.UseMvc(Route =>{
            Route.MapRoute(
                name:"default",
                template: "{Controller=Name}/{action=Name}/{id?}"
            );
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

For DotNet Core 3.1

Use below

File : Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{         

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
       
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Comment: What to do with all the services configuration lines?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
 services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false); or 
 OR
 services.AddControllers(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

Comment: What is the difference with option 3 in top [Sergii Zhuravskyi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58267385/52277)? 
Yo can just upvote an existing answer

Answer (score -5):

Use Below Code

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
            });
```

Comment: It would help if you explained *how* this code solves the problem.

Comment: Simply posting code is not a sufficient answer.  Please explain what/why/how this code will answer the question.

Comment: this is just boiler plate that comes out of the box and doesnt actually help the user with that they are adter

Comment: The above code will throw an error since it does not have {id? } as optional parameter app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/ {id?}");
        });