# Controller post [FromBody] Null issue when when migrating from .netcore 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-controller

I had a completely functioning program at version 2.2 
when migrating to version 3.0 and replacing

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

With `services.AddControllers();`

And replacing `app.UseMvc();`

With:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

One of the controllers is broken. (Other controllers which also has Post Method and [FromBody] Works fine)
The controller and the method broken is:

```
[Route("api/vm")]
public class MainController: Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Process")]
    public IActionResult GetProcess([FromBody]ProcessModel[] process)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

The Model:

```
public class ProcessModel
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ExeName")]
    public string ExeName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Path")]
    public string Path { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("VersionPath")]
    public string VersionPath { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Ver")]
    public string Ver { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Args")]
    public string[] Args { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Instances")]
    public List<ProcessDetails> Instances { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Multiple")]
    public string Multiple { get; set; }
}
```

The call I am making to `/api/vm/Process`:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Test",
        "ExeName": "Test",
        "Multiple": false,
        "Path": "Test",
        "VersionPath": "Test",
        "Args": {
            "IsFile": false
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "Test",
        "ExeName": "Test.exe",
        "Multiple": false,
        "Path": "Test",
        "VersionPath": "Test",
        "Args": {
            "IsFile": false
        }
    }
]
```

The app worked at production just fine for a few months. All I did was upgrade to .netcore 3, Now when I debug and get to the method at the controller I get null in a process variable

**Note:**
I used this thread when the app was broken at first place 
[Using 'UseMvc' to configure MVC is not supported while using Endpoint Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57684093/using-usemvc-to-configure-mvc-is-not-supported-while-using-endpoint-routing)

Comment: One possible thing is: Multiple is declared as a string in the model but in JSON you are passing as a bool.
declare boolean value or assign false as a string "Multiple": "false",

Comment: This is the possible string for your model:
[
{
    "Name": "Test",
    "ExeName": "Test",
    "Multiple": "false",
    "Path": "Test",
    "VersionPath": "Test",
    "Args": ["false"]
},
{
    "Name": "Test",
    "ExeName": "Test.exe",
    "Multiple": "false",
    "Path": "Test",
    "VersionPath": "Test",
   "Args": ["false"]
}
]

Comment: If your json bidding was working in .net 2 try with newtonsoft as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support

Comment: yea sounds like a system.text.json change.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you don't need to use `JsonProperty` if your property name is the same as JSON keys.

Comment: I know, it's in case I would change the name of The property so it wouldn't break

Answer (score 2):

Auto type converting is not available in new `System.Text.Json`, probably for performance reasons. You should use "Newtonsoft serializer" or use a custom converter. Some of your class properties are string but you are sending bool (Multiple property), int.

Using Newtonsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support

`System.Text.Json` Converter sample:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/tests/Serialization/CustomConverterTests.Int32.cs

Register your converter like this:

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new MyInt32Converter());
});
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to

Comment: that's lame from MS, they should put by default most parity in a way that we can strip down if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your `ProcessModel` has `string[]` type for `Args`:

`public string[] Args { get; set; }`

While in your json, you pass it as an object which results in the model binding null

```
"Args": {
        "IsFile": false
    }
```

Either pass `Args` as `string[]` like

```
"Args": ["IsFile:false"]
```

Or if you do want to change the json, modify `Args` to a Dictionary type:

```
[JsonProperty("Args")]      
public Dictionary<string, string> Args { get; set; }
```

Remember to add reference to `NewtonsoftJson` like others have said

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here in `Multiple` and `Args` JSON properties.
In JSON they are bool and object, but in `Process` model they are both strings. I am not quite sure how it could work in Core 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
Download and install the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" NuGet package in Visual Studio for Mac -I use Macbook Pro.

**Step 2:**
I have read [Migrate Startup.Configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to migrate my project to .Net Core 3. Basically all you need to do is to add the following to your existing setup on the ConfigureServices() method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // update Startup.ConfigureServices to call AddNewtonsoftJson
    services.AddControllers();
    ...
    ...
    services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(); 
}
```

And then on the Configure() method add the following:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    ...
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

These screenshots are from Microsoft:

[image]

[image]

**Step 3:** Remove the **FromBody** from the method signature. It is not needed in .Net Core 3+ anymore. So your end point should like this:

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
public IActionResult Login(YourRequest request) {

}
```

Also, I didn't add the **[JsonProperty]** attribute to the model properties. My request class structure is:

```
using System;

namespace Models.Communication.Request
{
    public class LoginRequest
    {
        public String Email { get; set; }
        public String Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```