# How to make a warning message being shown while coding on visual studio with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

You can view this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57684093/using-usemvc-to-configure-mvc-is-not-supported-while-using-endpoint-routing) first to easier to understand my problem. When I use UseMvc() method without using Endpoint Routing, the visual studio show a warning message while I'm coding. I know how to solve the warning. But I want to know how we could make a warning like this, I wrote some libraries and I want other people use these libraries correctly, remind them while they are coding.
[image]

Comment: This is a [Roslyn Analyzer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/), specifically [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Analyzers/Analyzers/src/UseMvcAnalyzer.cs)

Comment: canton beat me, but me too was thinking you may be looking for [Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)

Comment: Ah yeah, that's a better tutoria link @Fildor!

Comment: Many thanks to you both. You save my day, man.